# How to use JSON result from autocomplete as variable for another autocomplete

Tags: ajax, autocomplete

I would like to ask You for help mi to figure it out, how to use result of first Complete which is giving me a client number as #select_client_id in another autocomplete.
At one page, i'm selecting order from autocomplete list:

```
    $( function() {
    $( "#select_order" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "data/orderData.php",
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                  find_order_out: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#select_order').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
            $('#select_order_id').val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to input     
            $('#select_client_id').val(ui.item.client_id);
            return false;
        }
    });
  });
```

Then there is another input field which is selecting packages for this order, where i`m using a client id, from first autocomplete:

```
$("#select_package").autocomplete({
   source: function( request, response ) {
 $.ajax({
  url: "data/orderData.php",
  type: 'post',
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
        find_client_package_on_storage: request.term, client: client
        },
  success: function( data ) {
        response( data );
        console.log(client);
  }
 });
},
select: function (event, ui) {
 $('.select_package').val(ui.item.label); 
 $('.select_package_id').val(ui.item.value); 
 return false;
}
});
```

For now, i've got only one client, so variable is declared by:

```
  <script>
    client="1";
  </script>
```

How can i do it properly? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it takes a little bit longer than normally, but it wasn't priory to figure it out :)

Answer is very simple :)

In #select_order autocomplete, i've add:

```
 select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#select_order').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#select_order_id').val(ui.item.value);    
            $('#select_client_id').val(ui.item.client_id);
            client_number=$("#select_client_id").val();
            return false;
```

And at the end of body set a variable declaration:

```
      <script>
        let client_number = 0;
      </script>
```

That solved my problem :)